# Doctrine 2 repository mapping error XML

Tags: xml, zend-framework, doctrine, mapping, schema

I get this error that I'm stuck on and have been for 2 days now so I'm hoping some good soul maybe has a clue.

Using Zend 1 with Doctrine 2, doctrine is configured for XML schema files.
I use the doctrine console command to generate entities, proxies, repoistories and sql dump.

Generating everything works just fine, I only have to add the xml schema file and start generating. How ever, when I run the application I get this error:

```
Message: No mapping file found named 'Application.Models.Repository.Users.xml' for class 'Application\Models\Repository\Users'.
```

The file structure is

```
zend
 '-application
     '-Models
        '-Entities
        '-Proxies
        '-Repository
        '-Schemas
```

The schema file I am using named Application.Models.Entities.Users.xml (I have opted for xml, instead of dcm.xml) looks like this:

```
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping
                http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">

<entity name="Application\Models\Entities\Users" table="users"
        repository-class="Application\Models\Repository\Users" >

    <id name="id" type="integer" column="id">
        <generator strategy="AUTO"/>
    </id>

    <field name="username" column="username" type="string" length="50" nullable="false" unique="true" />
    <field name="password" column="password" type="string" length="32" nullable="false" />
    <field name="role" column="role" type="string" length="50" nullable="false"  />
    <field name="created" column="created" type="datetime" nullable="false" />
    <field name="lastLogin" column="lastlogin" type="datetime" nullable="false" />

</entity>

</doctrine-mapping>
```

It is interesting that it asks for Application.Models.Repository.Users.xml instead of .Entity. I have however just for dun renamed the file to Application.Models.Repository.Users.xml and then I get this error:

```
Message: Invalid mapping file 'Application.Models.Repository.Users.xml' for class 'Application\Models\Repository\Users'.
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: The XML you've provided is missing a closing tag : `</doctrine-mapping>`.

Comment: Yeah, it was unfortunately just on here.

Comment: To answer my own question, I had wrong entity name in $em->getRepository(). Now it's fixed and it works as expected.